# Linear regression with partial independence of observations

Tags: regression, machine-learning, independence, assumptions

I'm new to regression and I'm still learning so I apologize if the answer to my question is trivial/obvious.

I have a set of finite Categories say A-Z. Each of these categories has five different characteristics. My data looks like this:

Category | Characteristic 1 | Characteristic 2 | Characteristic 3 | Characteristic 4 | Characteristic 5

For each of these categories, I wish to record a continuous measure, namely my dependent variable.

However, I can't do with just one response for each Category; I need about 10.

Now, if these 10 respondents were different for each category, the assumption of independence would hold.

However, some of the respondents will be common across categories. For instance respondent R1 may be measured in Category A, F, G, U, R, P (at most 10). R2 may be measured in Category A, B, M, X, Y, Z. Each category will however, have all unique respondents.

I wish to regress the category and the characteristics to predict the continuous measure for future data (i.e., machine learning).

Is the design of my study flawed? How can I improve it? Is this a violation of assumption of independence of observations?